# Reducing bandwidth while using Facebook chat

Tags: facebook, bandwidth, chat

I live in place where the data charges are extremely high (~0,70€ per MB in Ethiopia, for example.)  If I wish to chat on Facebook, data charges rack up quickly due to the standard Facebook app's bandwidth use: always updating the stream, downloading all of the images and profile pictures, etc.

Is there a way to restrict or minimize bandwidth utilization while using Facebook chat, basically only transmitting the text data?  3rd-party apps would be fine as well.

PS: I already tried to download imo.im from the Google Play market - but this one is not available in Ethiopia.

Answer (score 1):

imo has a direct download link [on their Android webpage](https://imo.im/mobile_android).  There also seem to be quite a few other apps to try: https://play.google.com/store/search?q=facebook+chat&c=apps